# Magento 2 REST Api update "manufacturer" attribute values

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I try to update the attribute values of the default attribute **manufacturer**.
It has now empty values and I try to PUT about 500 values.

My address

`/host/rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer`

gives me **"Attribute with the same code"**.

I am pretty sure that PUT is the right option and that I already updated Items with PUT.

Comment: I found the problem, it needs to have the Attribute_ID within the body, then it works.

Comment: I saw that I can also Update using POST. Thisl leaves open the question what is the exact difference in PUT and POST.